# How do I modify the TinyMCE editor Add Media button to insert a thumbnail preview of PDFs in addition to a text link?

Tags: hooks, media-library, tinymce

We're still using TinyMCE as our post editor.

When Editors use the 'Add Media' button to select a PDF from the Media Library, they choose the preview image from the Attachment Display Settings at bottom right.

However, the result that gets pasted into the editor is simply a text link to the PDF but does not contain the image preview they expect.

In other words, the result pasted into the editor is something like this:

```
<a href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/mypdf.pdf">My PDF</a>
```

But what they expect is something like this:

```
<a href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/mypdf.pdf"><img class="thumbnail" src="example.com/wp-content/uploads/mypdf-thumbnail.jpg"/>My PDF</a>
```

I have looked at the uploads folder and the various preview JPGs -are- being generated for each PDF.

Is there a hook for TinyMCE in the Media Library code which we can use to modify that behavior? ie. again, when the editor inserts a PDF from the media library, the preview img can be inserted along with an href to the PDF?

Or is there a commonly used plug-in?